# PHP Includes and relative/absolute pathing not working

Tags: php, html

In my site index.php sits in the / director and then I have several other .php files that reside in /episodes/10/ (10 being the episode number).

My paths to the includes in index.php are simply `<?php include "includes/head.php"; ?>`. These paths don't work inside the .php files that are located in episodes/10/ folder. So I made the paths `<?php include "../../includes/head.php"; ?>` but to no avail. I've tried making them all absolute paths by using `<?php include "/includes/head.php"; ?>` but that didn't work either.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: allowing the use of `..` in include paths is risky so it's not possible under a number of security configurations

Comment: Absolute paths are the best. `/var/www/html/includes/head.php`

Comment: Like said, I tried using simply "/". If I did it from the root of my computer it'd be worthless once I push it live. I'd have to change all the paths again.

Answer (score 3):

A solution that will work regardless from which subdirectory it is run:

```
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 'includes/head.php');
```

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't do anything? Am I supposed to replace "DOCUMENT_ROOT" with a path? I'm testing this locally using MAMP and then pushing to a dev server so I don't want to have to change paths a bunch.

Comment: No you dont have to replace anything, you can just copy-paste the line in my answer, and it should work fine on any host (assuming your includes folder is in your web root)

Comment: Interesting. That worked on my dev server, but not locally. Thank you so much.

Any idea why this isn't working locally running MAMP?

Comment: When you run it locally, is the script in a subdir, such as localhost/dev/index.php? If so, that would explain why its not working locally.

Comment: @Wouter, the **DOCUMENT_ROOT** SAPI parameter is recommended but not guaranteed.  `dirame(__FILE__)` is robust over all PHP 5.x versions as a basis for relative addresses.